# Getting error like Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, cors

I am doing Laravel project. In this I have folder name as onlinebookingmanager in localhost. And I run a command like `npm run dev`. After this I run the url http://localhost:8080/admin/login. Now i am getting error like

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I have installed plugin CORS but it seems doesn't working.

Comment: either run you server on default HTTP(80) port or set up "plugin CORS"(whatever it means) for localhost:8080; currently domain+port used does not match response of preflight(http://localhost:80 != http://localhost:8080)

Answer (score 0):

This issue due to missing header attribute `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which should be `*`.

Best way to resolve this issue is integrate the following library to your laravel project

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

This library provides CORS solution in middleware so in every request you will get perfect header.

Comment: After i added this middleware also I am getting same error

Answer (score -1):

Have you included following code in your app.js

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
 Accept");
 next();
});
```

Hope it helps.